# About FPS bones

Tags: bones

I was thinking about making multiple animations in my armature(rig) and i want to make all the animations with the weapons(a lot of them), i usually attach my weapons to bones for only that mesh and then i relationate the bones of the weapon and the character using constraints like child of( I keyframe this constraint).however, this makes me wonder that this would make my armature have to much bones for my game(I,m developing for android and the less bones you have the better is),it,s like for every weapon =two more bones in the blender file(not attached to characters armature more bones) , but i don,t know if the mesh is not rendered the bones as well aren,t rendered.

So, if the bones are rendered, another way to animate without making a lot of bones?